# Dans les contextes où « lier » et « relier » sont possibles, quelle nuance de sens est sentie ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, préfixes

J'ai lu [ce fil sur Wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/lier-vs-relier.460330/), mais je ne comprends pas la phrase en gras [sur BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3381):

> Formé du verbe *lier* auquel on a ajouté le préfixe *re-*,
>   le verbe *relier* partage avec *lier* le sens d'« assembler,
>   joindre des éléments » et le sens plus abstrait de « mettre en
>   rapport avec ». Il signifie également « établir une communication,
>   faire correspondre ». Les liens institués par *relier* semblent
>   extrinsèques, c’est-à-dire établis de l’extérieur, orientés vers un but. **Dans
>   les contextes où *lier* et *relier* sont possibles, une nuance de
>   sens est sentie.**

1. Quelle nuance de sens ?
2. Comment peut-elle être sentie ?

Prière d'utiliser ces deux verbes apparentés dans la même phrase, pour souligner comment le seul choix d'un de ces verbes peut changer la phrase et de proposer d'autres phrases que les trois données en exemple sur le susdit BDL, où ces deux verbes peuvent être échangés, indiqué par

> relier (ou lier).

Comment: Lili lira et relira ce qu'Aurélie relie, ça les lie ! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Lier et relier indiquent tous les deux un assemblage, mais "lier" est entravant alors que relier est connectant. Voici deux exemples (il y a sans doute mieux) où j'exagère la nuance.

> J'ai les mains liées à cette machine. = Je suis impuissant,
>   prisonnier, je ne sais pas utiliser mes mains car elles sont
>   attachées (fermement).
>
> J'ai les mains reliées à cette machine. = Mes mains sont connectées à
>   cette machine (plutôt dans le but de contrôler la machine: je peux
>   encore bouger et, probablement, me détacher facilement),